# Can't compile PHP 5.6 in Debian 8

Tags: debian, compiling, php, php5

I want to install PHP 5.6 in Debian Jessie and I'm following the procedures [listed in this page](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-php-7-on-debian/#nbspcompilenbspphpnbsp-as-phpfpm-and-fastcgi) (the server is using ISPConfig and I want to add this PHP version to the list of PHP versions available).

When I run:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/php-5.6 --with-pdo-pgsql --with-zlib-dir --with-freetype-dir --enable-mbstring --with-libxml-dir=/usr --enable-soap --enable-calendar --with-curl --with-mcrypt --with-zlib --with-pgsql --disable-rpath --enable-inline-optimization --with-bz2 --with-zlib --enable-sockets --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-pcntl --enable-mbregex --enable-exif --enable-bcmath --with-mhash --enable-zip --with-pcre-regex --with-pdo-mysql --with-mysqli --with-mysql-sock=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-png-dir=/usr --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-openssl=/opt/openssl --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data --with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-ftp --with-kerberos --with-gettext --with-xmlrpc --with-xsl --enable-opcache --enable-fpm
```

I get the following error:

```
checking for GNU gettext support... yes
checking for bindtextdomain in -lintl... no
checking for bindtextdomain in -lc... no
configure: error: Unable to find required gettext library
```

The thing is I have gettext installed and I do not know how to go on with this. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: I know it might not be your choice but I couldn't advise you to continue using ISPConfig, if you want a simple system don't use that monstrosity overkill featureful monster, I might have things wrong but I walways find it way too complex for a simple hosting serveur

Comment: The reasons you are against ISPConfig is due to its complexity? Performance? What other options do you recommend instead of ISPConfig?

Comment: Well I would consider building a small script that deploy a standard configuration on the server. But that's opinion base, My experience with ISPConfig is very confuse as this do a lot of things I don't understand and the documentation is not really exhaustive (the complete installation procedure is not even on their website)

Comment: I'm very familiar with ISPConfig but thanks for sharing your experience. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure you've installed the following packages:

```
# apt-get install libxml2-dev libz-dev libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libmcrypt-dev libpq-dev libxslt-dev
```

I've tried the configuration command within a Docker container [1] and the command finished successfully. Mind

- the change in `./configure` command: `--with-openssl=/opt/openssl` was removed
- the absence of `gettext` package

[1] Dockerfile for configuring PHP 5.6 within Debian Jessie (directives are split to emphasize the order for each required package but a condensed form [2] would have work the same)

```
FROM debian:jessie                                                                                                                                                                         

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y wget

RUN wget http://de2.php.net/get/php-5.6.33.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror -O php-5.6.33.tar.bz2

RUN apt-get install -y bzip2

RUN tar jxf ./php-5.6.33.tar.bz2

RUN apt-get install -y gcc

RUN apt-get install -y libxml2-dev

RUN apt-get install -y libz-dev

RUN apt-get install -y libbz2-dev

RUN apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev

RUN apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev

RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev

RUN apt-get install -y libxslt-dev

RUN cd php-5.6.33 && ./configure --prefix=/opt/php-5.6 --with-pdo-pgsql --with-zlib-dir --with-freetype-dir --enable-mbstring --with-libxml-dir=/usr --enable-soap --enable-calendar --with-curl --with-mcrypt --with-zlib --with-pgsql --disable-rpath --enable-inline-optimization --with-bz2 --with-zlib --enable-sockets --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-pcntl --enable-mbregex --enable-exif --enable-bcmath --with-mhash --enable-zip --with-pcre-regex --with-pdo-mysql --with-mysqli --with-mysql-sock=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-png-dir=/usr --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data --with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-ftp --with-kerberos --with-gettext --with-xmlrpc --with-xsl --enable-opcache --enable-fpm
```

[2] Condensed Dockerfile for configuring PHP 5.6 within Debian Jessie

```
FROM debian:jessie                                                                                                                                                                         

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y wget bzip2 gcc libxml2-dev libz-dev libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libmcrypt-dev libpq-dev libxslt-dev && \
  wget http://de2.php.net/get/php-5.6.33.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror -O php-5.6.33.tar.bz2 && \
  tar jxf ./php-5.6.33.tar.bz2 && \
  cd php-5.6.33 && ./configure --prefix=/opt/php-5.6 --with-pdo-pgsql --with-zlib-dir --with-freetype-dir --enable-mbstring --with-libxml-dir=/usr --enable-soap --enable-calendar --with-curl --with-mcrypt --with-zlib --with-pgsql --disable-rpath --enable-inline-optimization --with-bz2 --with-zlib --enable-sockets --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-pcntl --enable-mbregex --enable-exif --enable-bcmath --with-mhash --enable-zip --with-pcre-regex --with-pdo-mysql --with-mysqli --with-mysql-sock=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-png-dir=/usr --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data --with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-ftp --with-kerberos --with-gettext --with-xmlrpc --with-xsl --enable-opcache --enable-fpm
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Matheus. It's now working. The problem seems to be with the extra --with-openssl command.